# Extract values from sample with trace

Tags: python, trace, pymc

I'm trying to reproduce an old code that uses PyMC

```
with pm.Model() as bayes_model:
    #priors
    phi = pm.Normal("phi", mu=0, sigma=20, shape=2)
    sigma = pm.Exponential("sigma", lam=1)
    #Likelihood
    likelihood = pm.AR("x", phi, sigma, observed=xvals)
    #posterior
    trace = pm.sample(1000, tune=1000, cores=1)
```

To get the sampled values, this used to work fine, but now it doesn't:

```
phi1_vals = trace.get_values('phi')[:,0]
phi2_vals = trace.get_values('phi')[:,1]
sigma_vals = trace.get_values('sigma')
```

I've tried to find what the correct (current) syntax would be but cannot find it.
Any suggestion is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found something that works, but I'd like to have independent confirmation:


`sigma_vals = az.extract(trace.posterior, var_names="sigma")`

`phi1_vals  = az.extract(trace.posterior, var_names=["phi"])[0,:]`

`phi2_vals  = az.extract(trace.posterior, var_names=["phi"])[1,:]`

Thank you